# sql update random between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, random, timestamp, sql-update

I've tried to update my database and changing dates. I've done some research but I did not found any issue. So I used two timestamp.

I've tried to do that method:

```
UPDATE `ps_blog_post` 
SET `time_add` = ROUND((RAND() * (1387888821-1357562421)+1357562421))
```

Now everywhere the new date is:

```
0000:00:00
```

Anykind of help will be much appreciated

Comment: Please share the DDL of your `ps_blog_post` table. Also, if you could please clarify what you are trying to achieve, it would be great.

Comment: In fact in my databse I insert some post for my new blog module. The trouble is that all dates have been removed, so I want to add new random dates between 2 interval dates (between 7 january 2013 and between 24 december 2013)

Comment: what type is `time_add` ?

Comment: time_add timestamp   Non CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the right idea, your conversion from the int literals you're using back to the timestamp seems off though - you're missing an explicit call to `FROM_UNIXTIME`:

```
UPDATE `ps_blog_post` 
SET `time_add` = 
     FROM_UNIXTIME(ROUND((RAND() * (1387888821 - 1357562421) + 1357562421)))
```

Answer (score 23):

Try this one to get timestamp between two  timestamps

```
SET @MIN = '2013-01-07 00:00:00';
SET @MAX = '2013-12-24 00:00:00';

UPDATE `ps_blog_post` 
SET `time_add` =  TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, FLOOR(RAND() * TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @MIN, @MAX)), @MIN);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/27851)

Comment: I quite like this approach. It's a little easier to handle than dealing with TIMESTAMP. For the lazy like me, here's a quick example (without the variables): SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, FLOOR(RAND() * TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2017-06-01 00:00:00', '2017-08-01 00:00:00')), '2017-06-01 00:00:00')

Comment: Also for the lazy, if you want the last 30 days: SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(SECOND, FLOOR(RAND() * TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), NOW())), DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select DATEADD(SECOND, - Round(259200 * RAND(), 0), getdate())
```

I state the current data and the you substract seconds from today.. The example take a random date from today and minus 30 days (60*60*24*30)...

Comment: this answer is not relevant to the above question about mysql