# How to generate 1000000 rows with random data?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Background**

Im working on some kind of data logger.

I want to try how much storage space I need for 1000000 (1M) rows and how Raspberry Pi deals with such big table. I want to run some queries with grouping, calculating averages and other performance experiments.

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` 
(
  `id`         bigint(20) NOT NULL      AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datetime`   timestamp  NULL          DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `channel`    int(11)                  DEFAULT NULL,
  `value`      float                    DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

**Question**

How can I fill it with 1000000 million rows **in MySQL**?

Requirements:

- `data.datetime` field: random timestamps but only from one year
- `data.value` field: random float numbers from given range (0.00-100.00 for example)
- `data.id` is autoincrement, no need to care about that
- `data.channel` is always 1, no need to care about that too

I know SQL a bit, but I'm not good in <s>PL/SQL,</s> loops in SQL etc.

EDIT:

To make it clear - im using MySQL 5.5.

Mentioned PL/SQL was my mistake, I thought PL/ stands for procedural features in SQL in general, not just Oracle.

Comment: Why solve this problem with only sql? Use a simple scripting language like Perl or Python and insert data as you wish.

Comment: Do you need PL/SQL or MySQL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775769/sql-update-random-between-two-dates

Comment: PL/SQL is for Oracle, but your tag says MySQL. They're nowhere near the same thing, and they are in no way compatible. What specifically are you asking about?

Comment: @jmmeier I thought it can be done in SQL with small effort. Im not good in perl or python. However im not bad in Excel... Maybe I will do that. Im not deleting question, looks like 2 people are interested.

Comment: @RyanVincent I don't understand what is purpose of that comment... Im building kind of slow data logger. I don't need to report interesting stuff as soon as possible. I want to compare weeks, months, years etc. I want to see how fast Raspberry can calculate week, month, year averages from 1, 3, 5 or 10 minute samples and adjust my measurement frequency to Raspberry performance.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try it with a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html) (replace `1000` with desired amount of rows, and `2014` with test year, also see [generate random timestamps in mysql](http://www.underdog-projects.net/2008/10/generate-random-timestamps-in-mysql/))

```
CREATE TABLE `data` 
(
  `id`         bigint(20) NOT NULL      AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datetime`   timestamp  NULL          DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `channel`    int(11)                  DEFAULT NULL,
  `value`      float                    DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE generate_data()
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  WHILE i < 1000 DO
    INSERT INTO `data` (`datetime`,`value`,`channel`) VALUES (
      FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01 01:00:00')+FLOOR(RAND()*31536000)),
      ROUND(RAND()*100,2),
      1
    );
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL generate_data();
```

Modify to your needs. To delete the procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE generate_data;
```

Maybe this can give you a start!

Comment: What is purpose of delimiter?

Comment: @Kamil Read more about [why changing the default delimiter](http://alextsilverstein.com/programming-and-development/mysql/mysql-the-reason-for-using-the-delimiter-statement-in-mysql-routines-stored-procedures-functions-triggers/) or here a tutorial [for getting started](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

We have [MySQL Random Data Generator](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/generate-random-test-data-for-mysql-using-routines) - easy to use procedure for generating the random data internally from mysql itself.