# Generate 5 million + unique rows of data

Tags: sql, oracle

Alright so I've looked around and haven't quite found something like this online

I have to write a script to generate minimum of 5 million unique rows of test data for a table, and these are the columns it needs:
•   First Name
•   Last Name
•   City
•   State

(can't be gibberish data)

suggestions on how to do this at all? If possible, I would appreciate some code examples to help me get going. The lecture notes and slides are completely useless and I have no idea how it's supposed to be done.

I found this, and the top answer looks like the closest thing to what I'm doing, **just not sure how to change/adjust the columns and attributes in the create table statement to match mine:** [How to generate 1000000 rows with random data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098747/how-to-generate-1000000-rows-with-random-data)

Comment: That answer at that link is just generating random numbers, which isn't *terrible*, but probably not exactly what are you looking for. Instead [creating temp tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671518/how-to-create-a-temporary-table-in-oracle) like @PatrickSJ suggests below and then Cross join them to create your [INSERT... SELECT...](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.6-en/insert-select.html) statement. Just make sure you sneak some funny first names into the list.

Answer (score 2):

Make 4 tables, 1 for each column and do a cross join that you select into your random data table.  In each table put your values, e.g., the first_name table has 100 names, last_name has 100 names, city as 100 names, and state as 50.  100 * 100 * 100 * 50 = 50 million combinations.

Just make sure each table has no duplicates.

Edit:
In the end @Jaluvshuskies and I had this discussion in chat.  For anyone who comes across this and wonders what we did:  we made the insert statements in Excel from a copy-paste list of googled first and last names, cities, and 50 USA states.

Each entry was 1 insert statement, e.g.,

```
INSERT INTO first_name (firstname) VALUES ('Sophia');
INSERT INTO first_name (firstname) VALUES ('Olivia');
INSERT INTO first_name (firstname) VALUES ('Emma');
INSERT INTO first_name (firstname) VALUES ('Ava');
INSERT INTO first_name (firstname) VALUES ('Isabella');
```

The then an insert from a cross join subquery and all done.

Comment: This is a good way of pulling this off. One of the few times it's acceptable to create a cross join.

Comment: with the 100 values in each table, do i manually have to enter? like if i just looked up 100 random first names (with no duplicates), would i just paste that for example? same thing with city, state, and last name

Comment: I'd just pull the names from a baby names and family names webpage.  Since this is usually already a list / single column tabular format I jump over to Excel to quickly add the ' ' around the strings.  Then use `INSERT INTO tmp_first_name VALUES ('name_1', 'name_2', etc)`.  Excel can easily format the list.  Just use `="'"&A1&"'," ` then remove the extra , from the last item.

Comment: ok sorry I'm actually having a lot of trouble figuring out the excel thing. I got the data in a column (atm im just doing first name) but i cant figure out for my life the formula. i did what you typed but all it entered was just the 1st value in A1

Comment: Are the names in a list, e.g., A1, B1, C1, etc?  Just go a drag-down (copy-down, whatever it is called) in Excel to copy the formula and adjust for each row.  See the little square on the bottom-right corner? Select that and drag.  Also, slight typo on the insert statement.  It is `INSERT INTO tmp_first_name VALUES ('name_1'), ('name_2')` etc.

Comment: nah, so firstnames are all in 1 column, which is column A. then at the very bottom i was going to put the formula but it doesnt seem to work right. every list of names i could find online were in a vertical list lol

Comment: In A1 type `'(''` that is 2 single quotes, not 1 double quote, in B1 put the first item of the list.  In C1 type `''),'` and again that is 2 single quotes not 1 double quote.  Does it look like `(' name_1 '),` when you see all 3 cells?  If so, the formatting is correct and you can just concatenate.  Then copy-paste the formula for all 100 columns (you can do it en masse).

Comment: is the formula still ="'"&A1&"'," ? (i put this in D1). cause i tried that formula and i got '(''',

Comment: Copy-paste of ="('"&A1&"')," gives...?

Comment: copy paste ="('"&A1&"'),"   give this: ('('''),

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160827/discussion-between-jaluvshuskies-and-patricksj).

Comment: If you were able to find lists of values and put them in Excel, you shouldn't have needed to create all those INSERT statements. There are other ways: export to CSV and import (for example using SQL Developer), or create external table to read directly from the CSV file.

Comment: True.  Didn't think of it.